# Should I update trigger API version?

Tags: trigger, api-version

I am an admin and have looking through some of the old triggers that are currently in our org. There are a few of them that are still active and do some important job but are set to API version 20. Should I update them to the newer version (44 or 45) using the UI? What is the purpose of that version? Possible downside of keeping it as 20? 
Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to see [my answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/70389) on what I believe you should do, but also this answer should be relevant.

API versions determine how your code behaves. At v20, it acts like Salesforce is on v20, while at v45, it behaves like v45. This is mostly compatible, but some functions, such as JSON.serialize, have different behavior depending on the API version. In other words, leaving it at v20 likely won't break anything for at least a few years, but upgrading it now might break stuff now.

Before you decide, you'll want to make a sandbox, run all tests, and make sure nothing breaks. Also, make sure you manually test the triggers to verify that nothing breaks (not all developers write good unit tests). Also, if possible, have a developer review your code just to make sure. Some non-obvious bugs could theoretically appear and be hidden by poorly written code. After you're satisfied, you should upgrade if possible; this will give you a lot more time before you have to do any more revisions.

Answer (score 7):

Apex language evolves every 4 months, with every Salesforce release.

I can definitely say there would have been many bugs in v20 which have been fixed over time.

Now there can be code, which relies on bug or side-effect of the bug to get things, done. Now when you increase API version the side-effect would go and in some case can break your logic.

eg: [Parameterized Typing and Interfaces](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/218126/what-are-the-risks-or-drawbacks-of-creating-parameterized-interfaces-using-of-th/218327#218327)

Your code might be using Parameterized Typing and Interfaces, which was removed in [v25(W13](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/42689/19118)).

```
 public virtual interface Pair<T, U> {
      T getFirst();
      U getSecond();
      void setFirst(T val);
      void setSecond(U val);
      Pair<U, T> swap();
 }
```

Now increasing API verson will make classes using `Parameterized Typing and Interfaces` absolute.

That being said, its always a good idea to have the highest available Api Version as it has latest performance and security patches. Try it in sandbox for few weeks and then move to prod.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever Salesforce releases a new API version, any classes/triggers written in older API version are still supported. That's one of the reasons to support [backward compatibility](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_version_settings_intro.htm) to have the API versions.

> To aid backwards-compatibility, classes and triggers are stored with the version settings for a specific Salesforce API version.

So to answer your question:

> Should I update them to the newer version (44 or 45) using the UI?

Depends. If there's no significant reason to upgrade all your classes/triggers to latest version, you can just leave them as is. Salesforce ensures that classes/triggers written in older API version still work. Usually it's recommend to sync up with the latest API version. Any upgrade should be carefully planned though.

> Possible downside of keeping it as 20?

The only issue you can encounter is if you are using [`ConnectAPi`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_connect_api.htm#apex_classes_connect_api) where methods  specific to an API version requires that particular API version.

> The classes and methods of the [`ConnectApi`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_connect_api.htm#apex_classes_connect_api) namespace are supported only in the API versions specified in the documentation

Answer (score 2):

Do you have developer resource available? If not, I wouldn't change it unless you have a reason to.

On the whole, bumping the API version should be fairly harmless. But, I would want a developer to look at the tests for the triggers and make sure that they looked to be comprehensive and effective before changing it.

There are some breaking changes in API version changes. For example this issue:

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000jfXtAAI

> Go to dev console or workbench:
>
> 1. Execute the following anonymous apex: [WORKING AS EXPECTED]

```
sobject so = [SELECT Id FROM Contact LIMIT 1]; 
System.debug(so.get('Name'));
```

> Result: System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL
>   without querying the requested field: Contact.Name
>
> 2. Execute this similar anonymous apex: [NOT WORKING AS EXPECTED]

```
sobject so = [SELECT Id FROM Contact LIMIT 1]; 
so.put('Description', 'This is a description'); 
System.debug(so.get('Name'));
```

> Result: No exception is being thrown. The debug statement outputs
>   null.

If there were the right kind of bugs in your code (e.g. something relying on the above), it could have been going a bit wrong for years and bumping the API will make it fail loudly.

If you have good tests, then it will be picked up. If not, you'll have to wait and see if your users report problems.